# FragmentTransaction crashes after checking if (Fragment != null)

Tags: android, android-fragments

I was following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cDNoJc7azMs&index=17&list=PLonJJ3BVjZW4lMlpHgL7UNQSGMERcDzHo) tutorial on youtube and ran into a problem with the end result.

The goal of the tutorial was to introduce Fragment Transactions by having these buttons that add/remove/replace fragments in a layout below the buttons. It all went smoothly until the end.

If I hit the "Add A" button, it adds the Frag_A in the layout below, if you hit remove, it disappears. However, if you hit "Add A" 2+ times, then you need to hit remove 2+ times in order to get rid of all of them. Likewise, if you hit "Add A" and then "Add B", you need to hit "Remove A" first before you can see fragment B.

At the end of the video, they included an if statement in the "Remove" methods to check whether or not the Fragment was already there.

```
public void RemoveA (View v) {

FragmentA FA = (FragmentA) manager.findFragmentByTag("A");
FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();

    if (FA != null) {
    //remove the transaction and commit 
    }
    else {
    //Toast a message to say the FragmentA doesn't exist yet 
    }
}
```

So I thought I could add a similar thing into the "AddA" method to check if a FragmentA exists, then toast a message to say it's already there, and if it doesn't exist, to add it to avoid having so many of them get created when you only need 1.

```
public void AddA (View v) {

FragmentA FA = (FragmentA) manager.findFragmentByTag("A");
FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();

    if (FA != null) {
    Toast.maketext(this, "Fragment already exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()); 
    }
    else {
    transaction.add(FA);
    transaction.commit();
    }
}
```

However, this made it so when you hit "AddA", the program just gives an unexpected error and quits. Looking at the Logcat (I just started learning last week so I don't know what everything means), I noticed a line mentioning a `nullpointerexception` at:

```
transaction.add(FA);
```

Meanwhile, IntelliJ is saying that:

```
if (FA != null)
```

Is always true, and FA == is always false. I also tried appending && isvisible but that didn't make a difference either. Is there any ideas as to why this would happen?

This is my first post and I couldn't find an answer for this on google/searching.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code:

```
if (FA != null) { // here FA is not null
    Toast.maketext(this, "Fragment already exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()); }
else {   // here, FA is null!
    transaction.add(FA);   // same as transaction.add(null);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

In the `else` block, you're missing some code where you would create a new fragment in FA, before adding it to the transaction.

```
if (FA != null) {
    Toast.maketext(this, "Fragment already exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()); }
else {
    // Create a new fragment here and set it to FA
    transaction.add(FA);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

Comment: I tried making a new FragmentA before the loop, otherwise it couldn't check if FA was null or not.
> FragmentA FA = new FragmentA();
> FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
> if (FA != null)
>     { Toast.maketext(this, "Fragment already exists, Toast.LENGTH.SHORT).show()); }
> else {
> transaction.add(FA);
> transaction.commit(); }

To no avail, it still crashes here. Then i tried putting a 
>FragmentA FA2 = FA;
In the else loop, but then even if the Fragment doesn't exist yet, it's toasting the message?